# How to convert an HTML code to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Here is my HTML code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

function myFunction() { }
```

So I want to convert it to Javascript. I mean how to implement above HTML line using Javascript. There is no id for the Click Me Button.Here is some part of IRCTC New Planner Page

```
<td id="plan" class="rf">
    <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'15901',_jd,'2A','KJM','BBS','4d2d393435342d3133',_tt,true)">2A</a> 
    <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'15901',_jd,'3A','KJM','BBS','4d2d393435342d3133',_tt,true)">3A</a> 
    <a onclick="availFareEnq(this,'15901',_jd,'SL','KJM','BBS','4d2d393435342d3133',_tt,true)">SL</a> 
    <span style="display:none;" id="ttf">O,</span>
</td>
```

I want a javascript code which will choose perfect Button(2A,3A,SL) and automatically press the class button.

Comment: It really is not too clear exactly what you are asking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the button an ID. Seriously. Anything else will be extremely ugly and unreliable:

```
document.getElementById('your-new-id').onclick = function() {
    // do stuff
};
```

Without an ID you'd have to rely on the tag name. The following code would work but if there's more than one button it would select the first one (or any other one, not sure about that).

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {

};
```

Comment: Just to confirm, it does indeed select the first element that matches.

Comment: Yes,You got what I want.But unfortunately there is no ID for the buttons.Please look the qs again.

Comment: Tell me again why you cannot add an ID to those buttons? Also.. which buttons?!

Comment: Yes I did it  using anchor value.thanks ThiefMaster